# Regex to match multiple occurances IFF another string occurs

Tags: java, regex

I'm really hoping this can be solved in regex, but I fear not....

I'm looking for a regex that will return multiple matches of a term ONLY is another term appears in the same string. This is better explained with an example. Consider:

```
The numbers are 144, 424, and 345. Not 45.
```

I'd like to match '144', '424' and '345' only. (Any 3 digit number) - but **only** if they follow the term '*numbers*' somewhere before. So the following aditional example:

```
The numbers we are looking for: 234 & 992
```

Should return '234' and '992' only.

The following sentence should not match anything:

```
Some examples: 234, 244 and 12
```

I thought I was onto something with the following regex:

```
(?<=numbers\b)(?:.|\n)*?\b(\d{3})\b
```

But it only matches the first number. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? No manner of lookahead or lookbehind seems to work here. For verious reasons I'm limited to this only being a single regex expression, and I don't have the option to selectivly access individual capturing groups after the fact. So looking for a purely regex method!

Comment: You can't solve it with a Java regex if you cannot get Group1 contents.

Comment: Why not split this in to steps? First check for existence of the word and second extract the numbers.

Comment: For various reasons outside of my control I'm limited to a single regex expression :(

Comment: Try this `(?<=\bnumbers\b.*?)(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)`

Comment: Java supports variable length lookbehinds of finite repitition. If this helps eg with max 999 char before match: [`(?<=numbers\b.{1,999}?)\b\d{3}\b`](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyda342ar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with `\G`:

```
(?:\bnumbers\b|(?!^)\G).*?\b(\d{3})\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iKdO0p/1)

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- `(?!^)` avoids matching `\G` at line start

Comment: Not sure it will help: "*I don't have the option to selectivly access individual capturing groups*"

Comment: Yep, this won't work for me, as it captures more than I need (like 'numbers')

Comment: You wrote `So looking for a purely regex method!` and this is a pure regex way. There is no `\K` available in Java otherwise for PCRE it is can be a simple: `(\bnumbers\b|(?!^)\G).*?\K\b\d{3}\b`

Comment: In your example, capture group 1 will contain the term 'numbers' - I'd like just the matching numbers, if that makes sense?

Comment: Not possible in Java with infinite length of text between `bnumbers` and 3 digit numbers but as I commented above it is possible in PCRE with `\K`

Comment: Actually @anubhava your example almost works if I change the first group into a non capturing group: `(?:\bnumbers\b|(?!^)\G).*?\K\b\d{3}\b` however, the `\K` isn't valid in Java (which I'm using) - so close!

Comment: Without any groups you will get 3 digit number at the end of the match but it will have other characters before that as well

Comment: @anubhava I'll mark your comment as the answer as I think it gets me what I want, provided I alter your example with a non-capturing group for the text. So I end up with: `(?:\bnumbers\b|(?!^)\G).*?\b(\d{3})\b`